# PHP OOP accessing variable in a conditional statement

Tags: php, oop

*objects/myClass.php*

```
class myClass
{
    public $curID;

    function get_next_id($type)
    {
        if($type == '1')
        {
            $this->enquiryID = "CAT" . $row['nextEnquiryID'];
            $this->curID = $this->enquiryID;
        }
        elseif($type == '2')
        {
            $this->enquiryID = "GE" . $row['nextEnquiryID'];
            $this->curID = $this->enquiryID;
        }
        elseif($type == '3')
        {
            $this->enquiryID = $row['nextEnquiryID'];
            $this->curID = $this->enquiryID;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to then access the new value of curID when it changes in another file.

*index.php*

So I try to do this:

```
<?php
    include_once("objects/myClass.php");
    echo ($myClass->curID);
?>
```

However I dont see any output at all. The conditional statement is going to give a different type based on:

```
<select class="form-control" name="enquiryType" id="enquiryType">
                <option value="1">Enquiry 1</option>
                <option value="2">Enquiry 2</option>
                <option value="3">Enquiry 3</option>
            </select>
```

so everytime the conditional changes I need it to update the curID using the statement and then send it across just to echo it out for now so I can then do some other processing on the index.php

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Ill try to explain a bit more thoroughly. I have the Select with options(on index.php) these then feed in to my class and depending on what is selected I then check the enquiryType 1 2 or 3 and go off to a database to get the last enquiryID for that type and append either "GE" "CAT" or nothing to it. Then I set curID to whatever that new ID is. So if the last id was GE1 it will find out what enquiryType it is for instance say "GE" and append 1 to it so its "GE2" and then set curID to GE2 and then I want to be able to get that value back on index.php and just echo it out for now. Hopefully that makes a bit more sence sorry if the original question wasn't clear.

Comment: So what's the value of `$var`? And what is the context of `$this` in the `objects/myClass.php` file? Because it isn't part of any class

Comment: That should throw all kinds of errors.

Comment: Alright, there's quite a few things here. First of all; all of your class code must be _inside_ of the class when referring to `$this`. Secondly, you've never created `$myClass`. All you've done is create a class named `myClass` but you still need to instantiate it by using `$myClass = new myClass();`. Thirdly: You're seeing nothing because your code is full of errors - enable `error_reporting`.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
<?php
    include_once("objects/myClass.php");
    echo ($myClass->curID);
?>
```

Should be:

```
<?php
    include_once("objects/myClass.php");
    $myClass = new myClass();
    echo ($myClass->curID);
?>
```

Edit: 
Based on your comment, it seems that your class is expecting at least one parameter to be passed into the construct:

```
<?php
    include_once("objects/myClass.php");
    $someParameter = 'some data';

    $myClass = new myClass($someParameter);
    echo ($myClass->curID);
?>
```

Without seeing the full class it's difficult to determine what the __construct() function is expecting.

EDIT:

I've decided to fill in some missing data, here's a simple example:

```
<?php 
// objects/myClass.php
class myClass
{

    // $enquiryID was missing in your class
    public $enquiryID;
    public $curID;

    function get_next_id($type)
    {
        // This array was missing as well, so here it's been faked
        $row = array('nextEnquiryID'=>1);


        if ($type=='1')
        {
            $this->enquiryID = "CAT".$row['nextEnquiryID'];
            $this->curID = $this->enquiryID;

        }
        else if ($type=='2')
        {
            $this->enquiryID = "GE".$row['nextEnquiryID'];
            $this->curID = $this->enquiryID;
        }
        else if ($type=='3')
        {
            $this->enquiryID = $row['nextEnquiryID'];
            $this->curID = $this->enquiryID;

        }

    }
```

And the other file:

```
<?php
include_once("object/myClass.php");
$someParameter = 'some data';

$myClass = new myClass($someParameter);

// Call get_next_id(), passing in the $type 
$myClass->get_next_id(1);

// Now that get_next_id() has been called, we can load the value of $myClass->curID
echo $myClass->curID;
```

Comment: After adding that in my echo produces
Warning: Missing argument 1 for myClass::__construct()

I know that is a bit ambiguous without seeing my code, (unable to show the full she-bang unfortunately) but is there anything you can tell me from that?

Comment: That sort of error means that the construct function is missing a parameter, I'll update my answer to reflect what I mean

Comment: Although passing that in has cleared that error, I still don't see the value of curID echo'd out. Just an empty void! I think my construct was expecting a connection to the database passed in. So ive now passed :
`

include_once 'config/database.php';
                include_once 'objects/myClass.php';

                $database = new Database();
                $db = $database->getConnection();
                echo ($myClass->curID);`

Comment: Without seeing the database / database class, it's difficult to debug any errors that might occur from them. The updated example in my answer works as is, but is faking data that might be coming from the database. If you can get the example I edited in to work, then you can exclude this class as the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help I think it's possibly a bit of a lost cause without the ability to share the database and class files! Ill keep on plugging.

Answer (score 0):

carefully look objects/myClass.php there is an extra } found

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong syntax in class, as you close your class after public $curID, place this bracket at the end. Class is a template(factory for objects), you have to define an instance of this class before you can get a property of it like $object = new myClass();
$property = $object->curID; you can change this property by making a method in the class what will take an argument and assign it to the curID property. If you have any questions just ask. Hopefully i did understand the question correctly, sorry if not.

Comment: Yeh I noticed that I had put the bracket In the wrong place, hastiness of my part apologies. hopefully my edit has corrected that.

Comment: I don't think what it is possible to echo again without refreshing the page. As when you refresh your object will be lost. Have a look on how to pass objects to another page, like with use of json. Or work just with variables and ajax.